# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadValidatorELTag

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, weblogic11g

I have this error while deploying EAR File for ADF Application

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadValidatorELTag**

**Note :** the application work properly from Jdeveloper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that deployment profile has an  application accessibility to Model
just unchecked and every thing worked properly .

[image]

Comment: So I'm confused, did you leave it unchecked or did you set it to checked ? Thanks.

Comment: I just leave leave it unchecked, Because the ViewControler has the dependancy of Model